# Sass directory watch not acknowledging changes

Tags: css, ruby, sass, stylesheet

I have been using Sass for about half a year now and have absolutely fell in love with `sass --watch`.

Just recently (I believe after I updated Sass to 3.4.5), I am unable to get standard functionality out of the `--watch` option.

My directory structure exists like this:

```
Desktop
-parent
--project
---css
```

As you can imagine, I'm trying to watch the "css" folder. My command has always been `sass --watch Desktop/parent/project/css`. I even tried other things such as `sass --watch Desktop/parent/project/css:Desktop/parent/project/css` to see if that would work, but it didn't.

Any shove in the right direction would be appreciated. I just don't understand why this suddenly isn't working.

Sass is 3.4.5 and I just updated ruby today to this ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else encounters this problem, I have found a workaround by simply navigating to the directory I want to watch (via Terminal) and then executing a watch on the current directory like so: `sass --watch ./`.